# By using slack(free) variable, solutions of both min and max problems

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$$F(x,y)= 2x^2-3y^2-2x$$. $$\text{s.t.} \ \ \ \ \ \ x^2+y^2\le 1$$

By using slack variable (free variable,), I want to solve minimum and maximum problems.

I want to solve this problem for maximum and minimum just like the solution of the above example. I dont want to solve this question in other ways.  I cannot do it. Please help me thank you

---

**For example**, $$\min f(x,y)= (x-a)^2 +b$$
$$\text{s.t.} \ \ \ \ \ \ x\le c$$ where a,b and c are constant.

**Solution:**

Let $\theta ^2$ be a  slack (free) variable such that $\ \ \ \theta^2= x-c \ \ $ i.e.$\ \ \  (x-c)-\theta^2=0$

Then the Lagrange function is following

$$L(x,\lambda, \theta)= (x-a)^2 +b+\lambda ( (x-c)-\theta^2)=0$$

$$\partial L/\partial x= 2(x-a)+\lambda=0$$

$$\partial L/\partial \lambda= x-c-\theta^2 =0$$

$$\partial L/\partial \theta= -2\theta\lambda=0$$

Now let's take $-2\theta\lambda=0$

(I) $\lambda^*=0, \ \theta\not=0$ Condition

$\theta^2=a-c>0 \to a>c$

[image]

(II) $\lambda^*\not=0, \ \theta=0$ Condition

$x^*=c$ I.e. $c>a$
[image]
(III) $\lambda^*=0, \ \theta=0$ Condition
[image]

Comment: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not in your objective function?

Comment: I would rather write $x+\theta^2=c$ in your example (error in the sign?). So your constraint becomes $x^2+y^2+\theta^2=1$. After that, treat $\theta$ as a normal optmization variable, and use $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \theta}=2\lambda\theta$ to solve the system (it gives me 5 solutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $F$ is defined on a disc of radius one, which is a compact set. Therefore, the maximums and minimums are either on the boundary of the disc, or strictly inside the disc.

- Case 1: suppose they are on the boundary. In this case, rewrite your problem in polar coordinates as follows:

$$
F(r,t)=2r^2\cos^2(t)-3r^2\sin^2(t)-2r\cos(t), \quad \mbox{subject to  } r\le 1.
$$

But if we are one the boundary, then $r=1$ and your function $F$ is equal to $$F(t)=2\cos^2(t)-3\sin^2(t)-2\cos(t).$$

Derivative with respect to variable $t$ gives you the maximums and minimums **on the boundary** , namely:

$$
\max{F}=4\quad \mbox{for  } (x,y)=(-1,0)\\
\min{F}=-\frac{16}{5}\quad \mbox{for  } (x,y)=(\frac{1}{5},\frac{2\sqrt{6}}{5})
$$

- Case 2: suppose they are strictly inside the disc. In this case, the gradient of $F$ equals:

$$
\nabla F=(2x-2,-6y),
$$

So potential maximums/minimums are have coordinates $(x,y)=(1,0)$ (which indeed is inside the disc). In this case,

$$
F(1,0)=0
$$

We can conclude from these case studies that the maximums and minimums are on the boundary: the maximum is $4$ and the minimum is $-16/5$.

Comment: but, i want to solve the question just like the solution of example. i dont other solution ways. but thanks for helping dear kuifje. you explained so good:)

Comment: can you solve the question again by the example's solution way? please:)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your function as $$2x^2-3y^2-2x = -3(x^2+y^2) + 5x^2-2x = -3(x^2+y^2) + 5\left(x^2-\frac 25x+\frac{1}{25}\right)-\frac{1}{5} = -3(x^2+y^2) + 5\left(x  -\frac{1}{ 5}\right)^2-\frac{1}{5}.$$

Let the variable $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then you obtain $$F=-3r^2  + 5\left(x  -\frac{1}{ 5}\right)^2-\frac{1}{5}$$ with $r\in[0,1]$ and $x\in [-r,r]$.

If you want to find the minimum, then the solution is evident: we take the maximum possible value of $r$ (i.e. $r=1$) and $x=\frac 15$ (it falls in the range $[-1,1]$). The resulting minimum is $\inf F=-\frac{16}{5}$.

If you want to find the maximum, consider first the maximization problem for $5\left(x  -\frac{1}{ 5}\right)^2$ on the interval $x\in[-r,r]$. Clearly, the maximum is attained when $|x-\frac 15|$ is maximized, hence we take $x=-r$. THerefore, we can say that

$$\sup F = \sup_{r\in[0,1]}\left( -3r^2 + 5\left(-r  -\frac{1}{ 5}\right)^2-\frac 15\right) = \sup_{r\in[0,1]}\left( 2r^2 +2r \right) =4.$$

Comment: okay thank you. but i want to solve this question similar to example's solution way. i stated it in the question box. Please can you solve this again by the example's solution way. thank you:)