# Min problem by using Lagrange method

Tags: optimization, self-learning, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$$\min x^2+y^2 $$
$$\text{s.t.}\ \ (x-2)^2+(y-3)^2\le 4 \ \ \  \text{and} \ \ \  x^2=4y$$

Please explicitly solve this question by using Lagrange multiplier method.

I accept  $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=4$

And $$L(X,y,\lambda)=x^2+y^2+\lambda_1 [(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2-4]+\lambda_2[x^2-4y]$$

But I cannot calculate Optimal x y and $\lambda,\mu$ . I got ridiculus results:(

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the constraints include inequalities, you should use a general version of Lagrange multipliers: the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

Comment: I know you said "Lagrange multiplier", but, even if just for rechecking,  this problem can be easily solved using ideas from algebraic geometry (Circles, parabolas, .... ).

Comment: As Solitary suggested, you *can* use KKT, but in this situation it is not entirely necessary. You can first ignore the inequality constraint, and use Lagrange multipliers to find any critical points satisfying just the equality constraint. Then you throw out any critical points which don't satisfy the inequality constraint. Then you adjoin the inequality constraint as an *equality* constraint, solve the problem again, and then choose the smallest value that you found. In this case this is a pretty easy way to proceed, because there are only a few points on both the parabola and the circle.

Comment: If it is not required to solve it analytically, a geometric method would be very handy.

Comment: @Solitary joonas Ilmavirta's solution is very good:)

Comment: Just a proposal, haha. If you like, you can try by yourself to treat these equations as circles and parabola. After drawing the picture, you can find the answer immediately without doing any calculation.

Comment: yes, i solved this question by graphing as well. thanks:) @solitary

Comment: @Solitary please look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545943/by-using-slackfree-variable-solutions-of-both-min-and-max-problems but i want to solve it in the solution way of the example. please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your conditions is $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2\le 4$.
This leaves two cases: either $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=4$ or $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2<4$.
(That is, the point $(x,y)$ is either in the interior or at the boundary of the disc. Treat these separately.)

In the first case you have two conditions for two variables.
Therefore there is no need to use Lagrange's method.
Instead, you can solve the pair
$$
\begin{cases}
(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=4\\
x^2=4y
\end{cases}
$$
for $(x,y)$.
You will get two solutions and you can calculate the value of your function at these points.

In the second case you can use Lagrange's method with one constraint: $x^2=4y$.
If this method gives you points that do not satisfy $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2<4$, throw them away.

You will get a short list of possible minimum points.
Calculate the values to see which one it is.

---

**Some more details** (which may contain errors):

In the first case, you can substitute $y=\frac14x^2$ into the first equation to get
$$
(x-2)^2+(\frac14x^2-3)^2=4.
$$
This has two real solutions.
One ($x=2$) is neat, but the other one is unfortunately not.

In the second case, you can calculate just as you did, only with one restriction.
This will lead you to
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda=1\\
y=2\lambda.
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $y=2$ and the constraint $x^2=4y$ gives $x=\pm\sqrt{8}$.

**Edit:**
It's not necessary to look at the problem in the interior, since it's not hard to argue that that the minimum cannot be reached there.
See the comment by borisd below.

Comment: You are great!! I tried to solve the first case. But I cannot find optimal point as it's seen in the picture.  Please help me these optimal points.

Comment: And in the second case, I just can calculate $L=x^2+y^2-\lambda (x^2-4y)$ ? I will find the derivative of L w.r.t x, y and $\lambda$ And get other optimal points. Right?

Comment: @B11b, I added some details. The main point is in the idea to check the interior and the boundary separately. You should be able to do the calculations (assuming there is supposed to be a simple answer).

Comment: You are really great!!:)) thank you so much:) Also can you look at another question if you have time? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545943/by-using-slackfree-variable-solutions-of-both-min-and-max-problems As I am stated, please I want to learn solution of the question in the solution way of example. Please help me. I will be happy:) dear J.Ilmavirta

Comment: Isn't it $\lambda=-1$? As a remark, you can avoid calculating the other solution in the first case: prove that $(x,y)=(2,1)$ is optimal (with value $5$) by observing that $y<1$ is infeasible due to the inequality constraint. Moreover, $y>1$ cannot be optimal because it implies $x^2>4$ and then $x^2+y^2>5$.

Comment: @borisd, that's clever, thanks! I added a reference to your comment in the answer.